# Set Custom Values to PayPal's Billing Agreements created via API

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

Is it possible to set custom values while creating an agreement using PayPal's Billing Agreements API? I would like these values to be returned by the IPN system.

For example, I want to pass a "purchase id" to the agreement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> using PayPal's Billing Agreements API

Be more specific, there are several classic or REST APIs this could be referring to. Each have their own API reference on https://developer.paypal.com

In general there are two parameters you can use, which will be named slightly differently depending on the API request you are using to actually create the transaction or recurring profile:

- invoice or invoice_id :: by default must be unique, never before used for a successful transaction on your account, prevents accidental/duplicate payments
- custom or custom_id :: can be anything

Comment: Hi. I am referring to  /v1/payments/billing-agreements which is provided by PayPal-PHP-SDK

Example: http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/billing/CreateBillingAgreementWithPayPal.html

It doesn't allow setting invoice id. I can't seem to find anything that lets me set custom id either.

Comment: The PayPal-PHP-SDK is deprecated and should not be used for anything. Read the most up to date PayPal Subscriptions documentation here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/ .  There is no SDK for it.  The parameter custom_id goes in the subscription creation call.